# An inaccessible directory with a random name has appeared in my home directory

Tags: filesystem, directory

It's name is `KAzdyLisjm` and when I try to list it's contents or delete it, those operations never return a result. It does appear to occupy over 300MB of space though, according to `ls -lh`, from the parent directory. Applications like FileZilla or anything that traverses it becomes unusable.

Permissions seem normal:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 john john 353M Jun 10 21:44 KAzdyLisjm
```

I have come across only one instance of this on Stack Overflow but there are no answers.

Update: I have tried booting a live CD and repeating the suggestioins in the comments below but there is no difference. From the livecd, I also ran *fsck* on /dev/sda1 and it reported the partition as "clean". Running *badblocks* returned no errors and the smart disk utility bundled with Ubuntu reports nothing with the quick scan. I will run the full scan but unless I update this in the next hour you can assume those tests passed also.

Comment: Can root (using `sudo`)  view the contents?

Comment: What does `ls -al KAzdyLisjm` say? Does it return anything ?

Comment: @heemayl " when I try to list it's contents or delete it, those operations never return a result" OP

Comment: What does `file KAzdyLisjm` return?

Comment: @Tim yes, see here for output: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/11693014/
heemayl yes, see here: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/11693019/
Serg, it seems not to be the case for these switches
the_Seppi it says 'directory'

Comment: heemayl: both user names that appear in pastbin are the same  user. I meant to refactor them all but obviously missed one. Could you delete the second name from your last comment? Thanks.

Comment: @heemayl there are lots: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/11693014/

Comment: @TenLeftFingers do you have a backup program at all?

Comment: If you have permissions on all of the directories then you should be able to remove the `KA..jm` directory....what happens when you try so? use `rm -r`

Comment: @Tim, yes I have DejaDup installed and backing up to a different disk entirely. But DejaDup is no longer to complete because once it starts reading that directory it never seems to get out of it. rm -r never returns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

300MB of zero size files is few millions files in a single directory, it is gonna take time to remove

Since disc seems ok and nothing is blocking files try using mc (Midnight Commander)to delete KAzdyLisjm and **skip** directory scanning

this way You will at least see progress if any

Comment: I don't see an option to skip directory scanning in the preferences or in the man pages for mc. I also was not prompted with an option. Nevertheless, I selected that directory while browsing the parent directory and have started another delete process to see what might happen if I leave it overnight. See you tomorrow :) Edit: After some minutes I am prompted to skip scanning.

Comment: This solved my issue, thank you. And mc was the right tool for the job as it was able to display progress in the form of a count of deletions within the folder. It was a matter of waiting out the lengthy deletion process.

Comment: Apologies for the delay awarding the bounty. I thought it was done automatically when I accepted an answer.